# Grails - First Ten Values only in g:each

Tags: loops, grails, each, gsp

```
<g:each in="${checking}" status="i" var="checking2">
<g:if test="${i<10}" >//Break The Loop</g:if>
//Do My Work Here
</g:each>
```

In above example, if its possible to get only first ten values from 'checking'. Suppose checking returns 100 values, I would like to access only first ten values.

I know that is possible by using max:10 in controller and returning only 10 values in list, but I want as stated above.

PS: I am new to this....

Comment: even it is a bad approach you should handle it in controller, but you can use any loop on the page using <%  have a for loop  %> for the iteration or anything you can also try sudhir's response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some thing like this

```
<g:each in="[0..9]" var="index">
  <g:set var="item" value="${checking[index]}" />
  //do whatever you want with item
</g:each>
```

In short, iterate over range 0..9 and use index as index to your list.

Comment: If checking has less than 10 items, `item` will be null in the indexes after the last.

Comment: used this to do partial lists used on separate pages of gsp.

Answer (score 5):

You can use ternary operator.

```
<g:each in="${list.size() < 10 ? list : list.subList(0, 10)}" var="data" status="idx">
    ${idx} --- ${data}<br/>
</g:each>
```

Answer (score 2):

Referring to [Groovy JDK API Documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#take(int)) you can use take() to reduce the List *before* looping

```
<g:each in="${checking.take(10)}" status="i" var="checking2">
```

//Do your Work Here

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<g:set var="checkings" value="${checking[0..(Math.min(checking.size()-1, 9))]}" />
<g:each in="${checkings}" status="i" var="checking2">
</g:each>
```